# unable to fetch url content by using ui.router

Tags: html, angularjs

my html code

```
<!doctype Html>
<html lang="en">
<head >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.16/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="first.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<a href="first">firstname</a>
<div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

and my js goes down here

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,) {

     $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: 'first',
            templateUrl: 'msg.html '
        })
});
```

and msg.html

```
<div >

hello world
</div>
```

I dont know why i am unable to fetch the url content its throwing an error like object not found any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use, `ui-sref` instead of `href`

```
 <a ui-sref="home">firstname</a>
```

So code will be,

index.html:

```
<!doctype Html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">

    <a ui-sref="home">firstname</a>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Script:**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"]);

    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: 'first',
            templateUrl: 'msg.html '
        })
    });
})();
```

**msg.html**

```
<div>
  Hello World
</div>
```

[**Here is the documentation**](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.4.2/#/api/ui.router)

[**Please check this DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fx4R8p?p=preview)

Comment: yea i tried it but   i got an error   like::::::Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: its not fetching an msg.html

Comment: I added an example , please check

Comment: i m unable to open plunker @ sravan

Comment: have u added  @sravan

Comment: @pradeep, I added please check

Comment: @pradeep Do you using local server for this app? or you doing by .html file opening on chrome?

Comment: i m using local server

Comment: localserver means? xampp or any ?

Comment: [Please check this plunker I added your code in this](https://plnkr.co/edit/eamLVO?p=preview)

Comment: i m using Xammp@ mohamed sammer

Comment: @ sravan i m unable to open plunker

Comment: Check the link provided by Sravan! its working @pradeep

Comment: which link ? its throwing an error like import error

Comment: @pradeep plunker link which is in comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170653/discussion-between-pradeep-and-mohamed-sameer).